# Deleting Cloud Task from Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

I am attempting to have a Google cloud task deleted via cloud function. This is the code I believe I need based on the google docs.

```
export const deleteHearingReminder = functions.firestore
  .document('Hearings/{HearingID}/Accepted/{AcceptedId}')
  .onUpdate(async change => {
    const dataBefore = change.before.data() as data;
    const dataAfter = change.before.data() as data;

    if (dataBefore === dataAfter) {
      console.log("Text didn't change");
      return null;
    }

    const taskID ={ name : dataAfter.taskId };

    const client = new CloudTasksClient();

    const [response] = await client.deleteTask(taskID);

    console.log(`delete task ${response.name}`);

    return Promise.resolve({ task: response.name });
  });
```

When this function gets called I get an error

```
Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied on resource project 6cDNgaqLniz6kHGonePh.
```

where 6cDN... is the taskID I am trying to delete so my questions are am I not providing google tasks with enough info to delete this task that I am getting a PERMISSION_DENIED error? Also if there is more info I should be providing what are the corresponding field names because from what I see on google docs deleteTask only take 'name'. Any suggestions are appreciated thank you.

I really appreciate all the help so now my code looks like this.

```
const request = {
        name: `projects/${project}/locations/${location}/queues/${default_queue}/tasks/${dataAfter.taskId}`,
    };
    taskClient.deleteTask(request).catch(error => {
        console.error(`There was an error ${error}`);
    });
```

and it works so which is great thank you I still get an error in this catch method though

```
5 NOT_FOUND: Requested entity was not found
```

I have tested it several times with consistent results should I be concerned about this it does seem to be working as expected

Answer (score 1):

For the permission issue you need to give your service account used the role Cloud Tasks Delete in the IAM page

However, you are trying to mistakenly do the task deletion.

You can see [here the official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.tasks.v2#google.cloud.tasks.v2.CloudTasks.DeleteTask) regarding tasks deletion.

Try to follow the [example here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-tasks/blob/master/samples/deleteQueue.js) which shows how to delete a queue but instead delete your task

```
async function deleteQueue(
  project = 'my-project-id', // Your GCP Project id
  queue = 'my-appengine-queue', // Name of the Queue to delete
  location = 'us-central1' // The GCP region in which to delete the queue
) {
  // Imports the Google Cloud Tasks library.
  const cloudTasks = require('@google-cloud/tasks');

  // Instantiates a client.
  const client = new cloudTasks.CloudTasksClient();

  // Get the fully qualified path to the queue
  const name = client.queuePath(project, location, queue);

  // Send delete queue request.
  await client.deleteQueue({name});
  console.log(`Deleted queue '${queue}'.`);
}

const args = process.argv.slice(2);
deleteQueue(...args).catch(console.error);
```

The argument you pass needs to be the name of the task in the following format:

```
name=projects/[PROJECT_ID]/locations/[LOCATION]/queues/[QUEUE]/tasks/[TASK]
```

[Here](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/4a180bfff8a21645b3a935c2756e8d6ab18a74e0/google/cloud/tasks/v2beta2/cloudtasks.proto#L266) you can see how the delete task method works and what it expects to receive.

```
  // Deletes a task.
  //
  // A task can be deleted if it is scheduled or dispatched. A task
  // cannot be deleted if it has completed successfully or permanently
  // failed.
  rpc DeleteTask(DeleteTaskRequest) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      delete: "/v2beta2/{name=projects/*/locations/*/queues/*/tasks/*}"
    };
    option (google.api.method_signature) = "name";
  }
```

Comment: thank you this did fix my problem I posted my updated code above and It appears to be working correctly the task gets deleted however I still get an error `5 NOT_FOUND: Requested entity was not found`

Comment: Since the initial issue is now solved, I recommend that you open a new question with the updated code and the new error you are getting. I believe most likely you are trying to delete a task that is no longer pending in the queue (A task cannot be deleted if it has executed successfully or permanently failed.) so you need to change your code to try deleting it but if it fails then instead of crashing just continue normally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign to the cloud function service account the necesary permisions in order to delete the task. Assuming that you are running the cloud function with the default `PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com as` service account, just grant the `Cloud Tasks Task Deleter (Access to delete tasks)` role to the service account.

[Granting roles to service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts)

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't solve the problem although I did read the google docs you attach and see where this does seem to be the solution I was looking for so I am not sure what is wrong. Can I provide any other information that would help you better understand the problem.

Comment: I put a catch at the end of deleteTask and see I am also getting a `Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid resource field value in the request.` I assume this has to do with how I am passing in the values to deleteTask. should this be passed in as a http request?